# Как расположить 3D модель на сцене в указанных координатах?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

я пытаюсь сделать следующее
У меня есть тег video, в котором отображается картинка с моей камеры.
У меня есть модель, которая отображается на сцене. Изначально она отображается по центру. В качестве фона сцены (scene.background) используется картинка с моего video. С помощью tracking.js я определяю расположение лица человека в окне. 
Как мне расположить модель на сцене в том месте, где найдено лицо ?
К примеру лицо определилось в левом верхнем углу окна. Мне нужно расположить мою модель на сцене тоже в левом верхнем углу. Как это сделать?
Я имею только координаты x,y. А для сцены нужны x,y,z и как я понял, они должны быть в диапазоне [-1; 1]

Comment: В диапазоне от -1 до 1 оно нужно только для определения координат на экране чтобы потом можно было пробросить луч из камеры и найти его пересечение с математически заданной плоскостью (см. пример работы с `THREE.Raycaster()`), только вместо мыши (и ее координат на экране) используются найденные координаты лица (с последующим преобразованием их в нормализованные, те самые [-1;1]). Можно посмотреть, как работает `THREE.Raycaster()` с `THREE.Plane()` в примере про [кубы](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=dragg#webgl_interactive_draggablecubes) в файле `DragControls.js`

Comment: Я смотрел пример THREE.Raycaster(), на основе сделал следующее https://jsfiddle.net/qv8jbryz/ x,y это центр квадрата, в котором нашло лицо. И как в примере делаю raycaster.setFromCamera( points, camera ); Потом делаю raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children ) и получаю пустой массив. Почему так?

Comment: @prisoner849, я вижу вы хорошо разбираетесь в этой теме. Вы можете ответить на вопросы за пределами форума? я новичок и у меня очень много таких вопросов возникает :(

Comment: Не-не-не, это делается иначе. Нужно искать пересечение не с объектами на сцене. Посмотрите в справке про `THREE.Plane()` и про `THREE.Ray()`, а так же исходный код [DragControls.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/65a6875d604853fa8a73badf1c39a927997073af/examples/js/controls/DragControls.js#L72)

Comment: Вне Stackoverflow есть форум по Three.js )) Как я говорил уже - он аглоязычный https://discourse.threejs.org/. Но личные сообщения там никто не запрещает писать на русском языке :) Да и народ там достаточно приветливый (навроде меня :D )

Comment: @prisoner849, спасибо за ответы. Буду разбираться) За пределами форума, как я понял ответов Вы не даёте, за компенсацию Вашего времени?

Comment: Я речь про то веду, что если есть желание общаться вне Stackoverflow - добро пожаловать на форум. Там есть личные сообщения, и уже там можно рассказать - по каким информационным каналам можно продолжить общение :) На счет компенсации времени - мысль исключительно верная, но я не настолько жаден до очков репутации чтобы из-за этого отказать в помощи новичку :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, концепт того, как работать с `THREE.Plane()` и `THREE.Raycaster()`:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var obj = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25, 8, 6), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "red",
  wireframe: true
}));
scene.add(obj);

var plane = new THREE.Plane().setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), scene.position); // будем искать пересечение луча с этой плоскостью
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var points = new THREE.Vector2();

function convertPoints(x, y) {
  points.x = (x / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  points.y = -(y / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
}

btnPositioning.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // координаты центра квадрата - [75;75]
  convertPoints(75, 75);
  raycaster.setFromCamera(points, camera);
  let pointOfIntersection = new THREE.Vector3();
  raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, pointOfIntersection);
  obj.position.copy(pointOfIntersection);

}, false);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnPositioning" style="position: absolute;">
Позиционировать!
</button>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid aqua;">

</div>
```

Comment: огромное Вам спасибо. В очередной раз Ваши ответы оказались полезными для меня :)

Comment: @detriat Рад помочь в очередной раз ;)